# convert uploaded csv file object to json object using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried the suggestions related to this conversion.I have read the file into file object and now I have to convert the file object into a json object array using angularjs.
The read file object is as follows:

```
id,category,type,name,value,isEnabled,key
1,kk,t,dsa,3,FALSE,A
2,jj,h,gdfjkl,5,FALSE,A
3,jj,u,hdg,9,FALSE,A
4,jj,p,rwe,7,FALSE,A
```

The respones variable contains the read file.Below is the controller file:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('app');
myApp.controller('FileUploadController', function ($scope, fileUploadService) {

    $scope.uploadFile = function () {
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log("file::"+file);
        var fileVal=[{}];
       /* var uploadUrl = "../server/service.php", //Url of webservice/api/server*/
        var uploadUrl = "../server/Book1.csv",
            promise = fileUploadService.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
 console.log("promise"+promise);

        promise.then(function (response) {
            $scope.serverResponse = response;
 console.log("serverResponse::"+response);
 var splitvar=",";
 var splitnewline="\n";
 for(var i=0;i<(response!=null);i++){
if(response[i]==splitvar){
    fileVal[i]=response[i];
}
else if(response[i]==splitnewline){     
}        
     console.log(fileVal[i]);   
 };
 console.log("length:"+response.length);
        }, function () {
            $scope.serverResponse = 'An error has occurred';
        })
    };
});
 })();
```

Below is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>File Upload Demo</title>
<script src="../scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="directives.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="services.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="FileUploadController">
<h2>File Upload Demo</h2>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="myFileField">Select a file: </label>
                <input type="file" demo-file-model="myFile"  class="form-control" id ="myFileField"/>
            </div>
            <button ng-click="uploadFile()" class = "btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>{{serverResponse}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i am not able to convert the same into the json object.

Expected output sample:

```
[{"id":1,"category":"kk","type":"t","name":"dsa","value":3,"isEnabled":"FALSE","key":"A"},
{"id":2,"category":"jj","type":"h","name":"gdfjkl","value":5,"isEnabled":"FALSE","key":"A"},
{"id":3,"category":"jj","type":"u","name":"hdg","value":9,"isEnabled":"FALSE","key":"A"},
{"id":4,"category":"jj","type":"p","name":"rwe","value":7,"isEnabled":"FALSE","key":"A"}]
```

Any idea about the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are some nice directives available for such a tasks. You don't have to implement all the things all over again.

I highly recommend [angular-csv-import](https://github.com/bahaaldine/angular-csv-import) and here is [demo](http://bahaaldine.github.io/angular-csv-import/#/) of that.

Comment: but i have to pass the converted the json object to my http.post

Comment: it will convert the csv to json. u can access the converted json from the controller

Comment: no access to angular-csv-import package. need to check with other method.

Comment: its a bower component package no need any permission. use bower to download it `bower install angular-csv-import`

Comment: tried that as well. it is blocked. no bower package can be used.

Comment: Not sure about bower but some one forked `angular-csv-import` to add it to npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-csv

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement the cvs to json then find below demo example

https://jsfiddle.net/mohan_rathour/Lt3wjgfx/7/

```js
// This will parse a delimited string into an array of
// arrays. The default delimiter is the comma, but this
// can be overriden in the second argument.

function CSVToArray(strData, strDelimiter) {
    strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");
    var objPattern = new RegExp((
    // Delimiters.
    "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +
    // Quoted fields.
    "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +
    // Standard fields.
    "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"), "gi");
    var arrData = [[]];
    var arrMatches = null;
    while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec(strData)) {
        var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[1];
        if (strMatchedDelimiter.length && (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)) {
           arrData.push([]);
        }
        if (arrMatches[2]) {
           var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[2].replace(
            new RegExp("\"\"", "g"), "\"");
        } else {
            var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[3];
        }
        arrData[arrData.length - 1].push(strMatchedValue);
    }
    return (arrData);
}

function CSV2JSON(csv) {
    var array = CSVToArray(csv);
    var objArray = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        objArray[i - 1] = {};
        for (var k = 0; k < array[0].length && k < array[i].length; k++) {
            var key = array[0][k];
            objArray[i - 1][key] = array[i][k]
        }
    }

    var json = JSON.stringify(objArray);
    var str = json.replace(/},/g, "},\r\n");

    return str;
}

$("#convert").click(function() {
    var csv = $("#csv").val();
    var json = CSV2JSON(csv);
    $("#json").val(json);
});
```

```css
#heading { font-size: x-large; font-weight: bold; }
.text { width: 99%; height: 200px; }
.small { font-size: small; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="heading">CSV to JSON Converter</p>
    <p class="small"><a href="https://jsfiddle.net/mohan_rathour/Lt3wjgfx/5/" target="_blank">JSON to CSV Converter</a>
    <hr />
    <p>Paste Your CSV Here:</p>
    <textarea id="csv" class="text">"Id","UserName"
"1","Mohan"
"2","Sohan"
"1","Abhi"</textarea>
    <br />
    <button id="convert">Convert to JSON</button>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <textarea id="json" class="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: i have to upload file and then read its fields and convert it into json object array. don't have paste the csv file.

Comment: then you can directly push the cvs field data into an array.r